# insert merged fields and script to have Accept and Reject in custom HTML email template

Tags: email-template, html, visualforce-template

I would like to ask for your assistance on how can I insert merged fields in html custom email template.

I need to create html template for this message:

```
Dear ${contact},
The engineer working your case is proposing a resolution. Please review the information provided and let us know if you are happy to accept the resolution or if you have any further updates regarding this specific case.
Review your full case detail on the Support Portal to accept or comment further: LINK
Please be aware that if no response is received within 7 days, this case will be automatically closed and any further query will need to be managed through a new support case submission.

(INSERT ALSO THE SCRIPT BELOW AS ACCEPT AND REJECT BUTTON)
(function runMailScript(current, template, email, email_action, event) { template.print('<a href="mailto:test@test.com?subject=Re%3A' + current.number + '%20-%20SOLUTION ACCEPTED&body=%0A' + email.watermark + '">Accept solution</a><br><br>'); template.print('<a href="mailto:test@test.com?subject=Re%3A' + current.number + '%20-%20SOLUTION REJECTED&body=Solution rejected%0AWrite comments here:%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A' + email.watermark + '">Reject solution</a><br><br>'); })(current, template, email, email_action, event);

You may also receive a customer satisfaction survey; if you do, please take the time to complete as we value your feedback. This enables us to continue to provide quality support services.
Kind regards,
Test Support Services

Thank you In advanced!
```

Comment: There is a option 'Available Merge Fields' to add merge fields. Isn't it visible?

Comment: I am not sure how to insert the merge fields with being converted to html as string